# What About The Necros?

Tags: discussion

As far as I understand it a better answer is always welcome, but then I noticed when I answered a question that it got pushed up the list.

Was this only because it was a relatively fresh question?
Do adding comments have similar effects?
Is there a policy on necro-ing questions if they do in fact "rise from the depths"?

Comment: Necro is fine so long as you are actually improving the post, there are even badges awarded for editing and replying to old questions if you look in the badges section.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding an answer, or editing a question or an answer, bumps the post no matter its age.  Comments do not.  This is by design and makes sense to me -- if there's a new answer or some other improvement, we want people to see it.

Because edits bump, it's important to make them meaningful.  Don't just fix one typo; look over the whole post and see if there's something else that ought to be fixed while you're in there anyway.  Edits that are too minor usually won't be approved (if they go to a review queue), and if you make a habit of such edits you might be asked to change your behavior.

That said, we're trying to make this the best place on the Internet to get answers to questions about world-building, so please *do* improve old posts -- responsibly and bearing in mind the bump.

Comment: So necros must be quality necros ^_^. Nice to know about the edits. I tend to flurry edit after I post. I don't know why but I just can't seem to spot errors as well when I have two copies of my post in-front of me (. .;) I'll refrain a little more.

Comment: Well, if the post fairly new anyway, your edit-bump doesn't change the front page much.  What I said is more for cases where the bumping makes a real difference.

Comment: While I don't have the reference to hand, StackExchange encourages question/answer necromancy if you can improve the quality of the the information on the site. I quite like that policy.

Comment: How heavy a necro is ok, considering simple typos and minor mistakes? I tend to refrain from editing old stuff at all, but stuff that is 2-3 days old I'll fix, even if it's just a typo sometimes. Is that too old or are we talking weeks-old? Most visible posts are at most 2 weeks old at the moment anyway - the private beta questions have unfortunately fallen off the map besides some new users who are digging them up.

Comment: days old is fine. I think a week is the point where you start to consider if its worth fixing the flow, spelling and grammar. Generally, after its fallen of the "active" list, I won't worry except to add information or a new answer.

Comment: @ivy_lynx my opinion is that if you can improve a post, improve it and don't worry about the age -- but unless it's very recent (already near the top of the front page), don't *only* fix a typo -- make the edit count.  In other words, hold two conflicting goals in your head: make the content on the site better, and don't needlessly bump.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Although there is something to be said for bumping.....once in a while on other sites, I'll edit an old, unanswered post, and watch it get an answer in under 20 minutes.....

Comment: @Shokhet I agree that looking for old posts to improve, and thus bump, is a good thing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, holy necro, been doin' it wrong all this time!